# Disable USB partition from auto-mounting on Gnome 3.16

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, usb-drive, automounting

I have a Sony PRS-T1 ebook reader which is based on Android 2.2. When I connect it to my PC, it shows up as two USB partitions: READER and SETTING. The latter is a read-only partition, only useful the first time you connect the Reader to a Windows PC or a Mac.

How do I stop the SETTING partition from auto-mounting?

I tried adding `UUID="4EA9-C564" /mnt/tmp vfat noatime,noauto,user,defaults    1 0` in /etc/fstab but this does not prevent the partition from being mounted.

Answer (score 2):

First find out the UUID of that USB partition:

```
 $ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

The name of the soft link to device of this mounted partition is actual UUID of that partition, for example:

```
 ...
 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 09-07 08:07 ae44ddaa-0e0e-ee22-66b-983bc15159b1 -> ../../sdb2
 ...
```

so the **ae44ddaa-0e0e-ee22-66b-983bc15159b1** is a UID of this partition.

Next add a line to `/etc/fstab` (you will need root permisions), something like this:

```
 UUID=ae44ddaa-0e0e-ee22-66b-983bc15159b1   /mnt/tmp        ext4    noatime,noauto,user,defaults    1 0
```

The most important here is `noauto` option which will prevent from automount.

Comment: This prevents automount **at boot** if the device is connected but not when hot-plugged.

Comment: Well, it is working for me (Fedotra 20/MATE) for many hot-plugged devices (cameras, usb sticks, external drives (both usb and esata)). I have 9 entries like this in `/etc/fstab` and all of them are working.

Comment: This is the line I added `UUID="4EA9-C564" /mnt/tmp vfat noatime,noauto,user,defaults    1 0` and it doesn't work. FYI, the Sony reader is based on Android 2.2.

Comment: I thought I had a problem once with disabling `vfat` partition from __automount__, so I have found someone with usb stick with vfat partition, inserted it into my box. After it was mounted I found its UUID then added new line to `/etc/fstab` and reinserted stick and it is working - no __automount__ for this partition. The only difference from yours line (except UUID of course) is I didn't used quotation marks (`"`). When I changed line and added these quotation marks, the partition started to automount again. Get rid off those `"` and youi should be OK.

Comment: Tried removing the quotation marks to no avail, but I found a solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use the Disks utility.

1. Connect the Reader.
2. Open Disks and select the Settings partition.
3. Click the triple gear icon under the graphic.
4. Select "mount options" and deselect "Automount options" AND "Show in user interface" and click OK.

This created the following fstab entry:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Sony_PRS-T1_Setting_148427501057252-0:2 /mnt/usb-Sony_PRS-T1_Setting_148427501057252-0:2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

The device does not show in Nautilus and the `/mnt/usb-Sony_PRS-T1_Setting_148427501057252-0:2` folder is present but empty.

Comment: Basicly the same solution as mine, except using disk-id instead of UUID. Are you sure you get correct UUID?