# One particular partition doesn't show a notification when connected

Tags: gnome3, notifications, removable-storage

In Gnome 3.16, when you connect a USB drive, a notification is shown on screen. I've a Sony PRS-T1 that has two partitions that are shown when connected.

In the beginning I would get two notifications for the two partitions (READER & SETTING) but after some time I starting getting a notification for one of them only (SETTING). I must have disabled this notification without knowing.

Is there a way to restore the original behaviour?

Comment: This is result of disabling automount for one of a partition (your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232937/disable-usb-partition-from-auto-mounting-on-gnome-3-16/232950) - if you stopped mounting one of the partition what the notification you want about?.

Comment: The partition automounts. I'm speaking of the other partition, the one I want to automount. This question is only related to the other one because we're talking of the same device. Now that I stopped the Setting partition from automounting, I'm not getting any notification, even though the Reader partition is being automounted.

Comment: OK. Then I guess yours Disks utility broke something.

Comment: This issue has been there before I disabled the SETTINGS partition using Disks.